# Is it safe to use trace inside a STM stransaction?

Tags: haskell, stm

I have a transaction failing indefinitely for some reason, and I would like to use trace instructions inside. For example, to print the state of the MVar's before executing the transaction in this fragment:

```
    data_out <- atomically $ do 
        rtg_state <- takeTMVar ready_to_go 
        JobDescr hashid url <- T.readTBChan next_job_descr
        case rtg_state of 
            Ready_RTG n -> do
                putTMVar ready_to_go $ Processing_RTG n
                putTMVar start_harvester_browser hashid
                putTMVar next_test_url_to_check_chan  hashid
                putTMVar next_harvest_url hashid
                return (n,hashid,url)
            _ -> retry
```

Would that make the program segfault or miss-behave?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As long as you use `trace` for debug purposes only you should be OK. As a general rule, just assume that in the final production-ready version of your program there will be no `trace`s around.

You will never observe segfaults from `trace`. Its "unsafety" stems from it  injecting observable effects in pure code. E.g., in STM, when a transaction retries, its effects are assumed to be rolled back. If `trace` was used to send a message to the user, you can't roll that back. If the output of `trace` triggers a missile launch, you will have to deal with international side effects. If `trace` instead just signals the developer with "FYI, the code is doing X", this is not part of the core logic of the program, and is perfectly fine.

Comment: The missile-launching code will be kept then in the IO monad. Thanks!

Comment: I find it worth pointing out that it's not a single missile launch that gives serious international side effects in this case – it's the 735 nuclear volleys when the transaction was retried a bunch of times you have to watch out for. ;)